# Specifying project root when deploying to Heroku

Tags: django, deployment, heroku

**My Problem:**

When using *gunicorn* as my WSGI HTTP server, *foreman* fails to find the Django (wsgi?) application.

**Application Structure:**

In my Django application, I have things structured like this:

```
<git_repository_root>/
  <django_project_root>/
    <configuration_root>/
```

The `<git_repository_root>` contains the project management and deployment related things (`requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, `fabfile.py`, etc.)

The `<django_project_root>` contains my Django apps and application logic.

Finally, the `<configuration_root>` contains my `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`.

**What I have tried:**

My `Procfile` should look like this (according to the [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)):

`web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi`

When running `foreman start` with this project layout, I get an error:

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

**What works:**

If I move my Procfile from `<git_repository_root>` to `<git_repository_root>` it works locally. After pushing to Heroku (note: Heroku sees `<git_repository_root>`) I can't scale any workers / add processes. I get the following:

```
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

I believe I want `Procfile` in my `<git_repository_root>` anyway though - so why isn't it working? I also tried changing the `Procfile` to:
`web: gunicorn myapp/myapp.wsgi`

but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well phrased/documented question, btw.

Answer (score 4):

Treat the entry in your `Procfile` like a bash command. You can `cd` into your `<django_project_root>` and then run the server.

For example, your `Procfile` (which should be in your `<git_repository_root>`) might look something like this:

```
web: cd <django_project_root> && gunicorn 
     --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<configuration_root>.settings 
     <configuration_root>.wsgi
```

Comment: you perfectly got the question right and the solution provided was on point.  A question since 2013 well phrased and answered

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Procfile` back to `<git_repository_root>` and use:

```
web: gunicorn <django_project_root>.myapp:myapp
```

replacing the final "myapp" with your app's class name, presumably it is indeed "myapp".

... and read the error message: it is telling you that you can't import your worker class (`app`) by filename (myapp.wsgi), so of course saying `dirname/myapp.wsgi` won't work as well. You need a Python `module:class` syntax.