# Problems running `foreman start` / deploying Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, directory-structure, foreman, procfile

This is what my directory structure looks like (I've included only the relevant parts):

```
my_git_root/
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── my_django_project
    ├── app1
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── fabfile.py
    ├── app2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── my_django_project
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings
        │   ├── base.py
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── local.py
        │   ├── production.py
        │   └── staging.py
        ├── static
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Following the [official Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django), here's what I have in my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn my_django_project.wsgi
```

But when I run the `foreman start`, command, I get a long traceback that ends with `ImportError: No module named my_django_project.wsgi.`.

Moving `Procfile` from `git_root/` to `my_django_project/` (the Django project root) seems to work (like what was done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076444/specifying-project-root-when-deploying-to-heroku)), but only locally -- attempting to deploy to Heroku seems to be ok, until you try to scale the web processes:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... failed 
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

It would appear as though [Heroku wants you to put the Procfile in the project's git repository root](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#declaring-process-types), but I've tried lots of combinations in `Procfile` and none seem to work. I've also tried:

```
web: gunicorn my_django_project/my_django_project.wsgi
```

in the `Procfile` but that results in `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

Specifying the python path doesn't work either; i.e.

```
web: gunicorn my_django_project.wsgi:application --pythonpath=/app/my_django_project
```

throws the error `ImportError: No module named my_django_project.wsgi`.

However, running locally with gunicorn from `git_root/my_django_project/` seems to work:

```
$ gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 my_django_project.wsgi:application            
2013-10-15 16:55:31 [5703] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-10-15 16:55:31 [5703] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (5703)
2013-10-15 16:55:31 [5703] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-10-15 16:55:31 [5708] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5708
2013-10-15 16:56:04 [5703] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
2013-10-15 16:56:04 [5703] [INFO] SIGWINCH ignored. Not daemonized
```

So my guess is that the syntax in my `Procfile` is incorrect, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out while writing this question!

What I had to do was set the `--pythonpath` option to point to my django project root, i.e. `git_root/my_django_project/`.

This is what I had in my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --pythonpath=./my_django_project my_django_project.wsgi:application
```

Now it works locally:

```
$ foreman start
17:04:02 web.1  | started with pid 6327
17:04:02 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:02 [6330] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
17:04:02 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:02 [6330] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (6330)
17:04:02 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:02 [6330] [INFO] Using worker: sync
17:04:02 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:02 [6335] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6335
17:04:04 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:04 [6330] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
17:04:04 web.1  | 2013-10-15 17:04:04 [6330] [INFO] SIGWINCH ignored. Not daemonized
```

And scaling web processes works now, too:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1 --app my-django-project                          
Scaling web dynos... done, now running 1
```

Comment: If my wsgi file is in the root folder, how would I be able to adapt the line that goes in my Procfile?

Answer (score 0):

Using your first scaffolding, where your Procfile is to the same level of my_django_project. I did this:

> web: cd my_django_project && gunicorn my_django_project.wsgi
>   --log-file -

Hope this helps.

--EDIT--

It's better change this file with the line bellow. Make sure you are on your master branch (I struggle with heroku pushing from another branch).

> web: gunicorn --pythonpath my_django_project my_django_project.wsgi --log-file -